# $k$-rational divisor classes and zero cycles of a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a number field, and $C$ a smooth projective geometrically connected curve over $k$. The divisors $D$ of $C$ are formal sums of closed points, i.e.,
$$D = \sum_in_iP_i,$$
where the $n_i$ are integers. The degree of $D$ is the integer $\sum_in_i$.

Some papers use the term *$k$-rational divisor class of degree $1$*, which I assume has to be a divisor class $D$ such that its degree, i.e., sum of coefficients of closed points, is $1$. But what does $k$-rational here mean? Does it mean that for each $n_iP_i$ such that $n_i$ is nonzero, we must have $P_i$ a $k$-rational point?

Also, if my understanding above is correct, a $k$-rational point on $C$ would then be a $k$-rational divisor class of degree $1$. But if $C$ has no $k$-rational points, does it then mean that it has no $k$-rational divisor class of degree $1$? I read somewhere that the *index* of a smooth variety is $1$ if and only if it has a *zero cycle* of degree $1$. Here index refers to the gcd of all the degrees of the closed point of $C$. But what is a zero cycle, and how does it relate to a rational divisor class?

**P.S.** A quick google search on *rational divisor class* and *zero cycle* does not return any sort of definition, only papers which employ that term, without defining it, so I'm genuinely seeking help in tidying this up.

**EDIT.** Here is an example of a paper using both terms: *Finite descent and rational points on curves*, by [M. Stoll](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0606465.pdf). *Rational divisor classes* appeared in Corollaries 6.6, 7.4, 7.7, Theorem 8.2, and *zero cycle* appeared in Theorem 6.4.

**UPDATE.** According to this [paper](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/flynn/arts/art24.pdf), a *$k$-rational divisor class* is a divisor class that is fixed under the action of $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)$. So if $D$ is a divisor of a $k$-rational divisor class and $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)$, then $\phantom{}^\sigma D$ and $D$ are linearly equivalent. So the elements of $\mathrm{Pic}(\bar{C})^{\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)}$ are precisely the $k$-rational divisor classes of $C$.

Comment: you should give an explicit arXiv paper reference where this terminology is used.

Comment: There are not so many alternatives - if $C$ is defined over $k$ and if $D:=\sum_i n_i[p_i]$ is a divisor, the only reasonable meaning of the notion "$k$-rational divisor" is that $p_i \in C(k)$ is a $k$-rational point for all $i$.

Comment: @hm2020 I've given a paper using the terminologies. So if $C(k)$ is empty, is it possible that $C$ has index $1$?

Comment: you should define the terminology properly - the notion "index" - what is the precise definition and where have you seen this definition? "Index" can mean many things and the name is used in many places.

Comment: @hm2020 But I did define *index* in my post! It is the greatest common divisor of all degrees of the closed points of $C$. [Here](https://www.math.columbia.edu/~dejong/wordpress/?p=1195) is where it can be found.

Comment: it could in fact be the case that $d_x=2, d_y=3$ and that $C$ has no $k$-rational points. Still $(2,3)=(1)$ and $Index(C)=1$.

Comment: @hm2020 Indeed, there's something deeper between existence of rational points and having zero cycles of degree $1$, according to the [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33774/existence-of-zero-cycles-of-degree-one-vs-existence-of-rational-points) I'm currently reading. I'll delete my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question:** "Also, if my understanding above is correct, a $k$-rational point on $C$ would then be a $k$-rational divisor class of degree $1$. But if $C$ has no $k$-rational points, does it then mean that it has no $k$-rational divisor class of degree $1$? I read somewhere that the *index* of a smooth variety is $1$ if and only if it has a *zero cycle* of degree $1$. Here index refers to the gcd of all the degrees of the closed point of $C$. But what is a zero cycle, and how does it relate to a rational divisor class?"

**Answer:** My understanding of the "stacks page" is the following: If $C/k$ is a smooth curve over $k$ and if $x\in C$ is a closed point, let $d_x:=[\kappa(x): x]$ where $\kappa(x)$ is the residue field of $k$. It follows $d_x \geq 1$ and $d_x=1$ iff $\kappa(x)=k$. Let $In(C):=(d_x) \subseteq R:=\mathbb{Z}$ be the ideal in $R$ generated by all such degrees $d_x$ for all $x$. This is a principal ideal and you define $Index(C):=d \geq 0$ with $I=(d)$.

One could imagine there is a curve $C/k$ with points $x \neq y$ and $d_x=2, d_y=3$ and $C(k) = \emptyset$. Still $Index(C)=(2,3)=(1)$.